# Split a string and update specific value in sql

Tags: t-sql, split, sql-update

Field value:03/2008
I want to split it from "/" and want to update year's value i.e. 2012 instead of 2008. I want to update the value in same column i.e. 03/2012 instead of 03/2008. In update query, I am not getting should i have to use substr and then how to replace the new value in same string?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to change field = 03/2008

```
UPDATE  table
SET   field = '03/2012'
where field = '03/2008'
```

bsm the replace you have in your answer is going to be slower

Answer (score 1):

Please try Something like this>>>

```
UPDATE table SET field = replace(substr(FIELD,2,6),'2008');
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommand using an integer to represent the number of months after day 0, '03/2008' becomes 1298. Alternative you could use a date (datetime if you are using 2005 or less) and set the day to 1 so '03/2008 becomes 2008-03-01. In order to solve your problem right here and now, here is a good solution, it ignores the value of the first 3 characters and replace the next 4 with 2012 if they have the value '2008'

```
update table set field = left(field, 3) + '2008' where field like '___2008'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys for your replies. Its working this way..

```
UPDATE    table
SET  field = REPLACE('03/2008', '2008', '2012')
where field="03/2008"
```